# Why L before dll path?

Tags: c++, path, dllimport

I've read the code that imports a dll into a project but I don't understand why we have the "L" before the path

```
module = LoadLibrary(L"freeglut.dll");
```

How I set the absolute path like "C:/VisualStudo/Project"

And how I set the relative path? like "../../Project1"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L is the string literal prefix to indicate that the string is made from wide characters (wchar_t).

In windows you have two version of LoadLibrary: `LoadLibraryA` (ansi) and `LoadLibraryW` (unicode), normally sone `#define` choose the proper version for your compilation. If you are using the A version you have to pass an ansi string, so no L is required, if you are using The LoadLiraryW you have to pass the string in Unicode, so the L as a prefix.

Comment: Just as an added note: the program is surely compiled as UNICODE only (otherwise they would have used the _T("STRING) variant). NT based OS (let's say everything but Win 9x and Millennium) natively work with Unicode functions and have "Ansi" (the A functions) functions for compatibility (they simply "wide" the string and call the W versions). Link with some infos from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc500321.aspx

Comment: Just as a clarifying note: wchar_t does not necessarily mean 2 byte (though on current windows implementation it is). Other platforms may potentially support other widths.

Comment: No, the _T() macros are only useful if you still target Windows 95 and its relatives. For new code it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

The L tells the compiler that the following string is a wide string. A wide string is compiler dependent, but in popular C++ compilers, the string is interpreted as a unicode string, and is encoded as such (encoding is compiler dependent). In the case of Visual C++, the string is encoded as UTF-16, which matches the string expected by the Windows API.